# protected routes issue switching from react-router-redux to connected-react-router

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-v4, connected-react-router

I am in progress of migrating my app to from `react-router-redux`  -to --> `connected-react-router` however, I'm seeing an issue. Currently, I have certain routes that are protected(requires authed users) i.e dashboard

```
export default function Routes(props, context) {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route
        render={props => <Authorization {...props} routes={AuthRoutes} />}
      />
    </Switch>
  )
}



const AuthRoutes = [
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />,
    <Route component={Error404} />
  </Switch>,
]
```

*The Authorization component looks like:*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Redirect, withRouter } from 'react-router'

class Authorization extends Component {
  isAuthenticated() {
    const { auth, app } = this.props
    const { search } = app
    console.log('====================================')
    console.log('Auth:', auth)
    console.log('====================================')
    if (auth && auth.token) {
      return this.props.routes.map((route, index) =>
        React.cloneElement(route, { key: index })
      )
    } else {
      return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', search }} />
    }
  }
  render() {
    return <div style={{ width: '100%' }}>{this.isAuthenticated()}</div>
  }
}

export default connect(state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  app: state.app,
}))(withRouter(Authorization))
```

After user logs in he is directed to `/dashboard` path and `token` is saved to auth in redux store(which is persisted to localStorage).

**THE ISSUE:**

- Upon 1st page refresh, console.log statement(from Authorization)
  outputs  that `Auth: {token: null}` and the user redirected to
  `/login`
- Upon 2nd refresh console.log statement(from Authorization) outputs 
  that `Auth: {token: <userToken>}` and the user redirected to
  `/dashboard`  *(correct behavior)*
- Upon 3rd refresh console.log statement(from Authorization) outputs 
  that `Auth: {token: null}` and the user redirected to `/login`
- Upon 4th refresh console.log statement(from Authorization) outputs 
  that `Auth: {token: <userToken>}` and the user redirected to
  `/dashboard`  *(correct behavior)*

Notice a pattern? It seems the `Authorization` component on **every other**  page refresh access the auth state before it has had time to restore from local storage.

If I revert back to using  `react-router-redux` the user is redirected to `/dashboard` correctly at each page refresh after login.

Comment: Did you sort this out? I've had the same problem and noticed that the placement of `withRouter` is important according to the docs. Try wrapping the connected component with the HoC `withRouter`. https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md  

`export default withRouter(connect(...)(Authorization))`

Comment: I'll try it, did it solve it for you?

Comment: My issue was that I was wrapping everything inside `ConnectedRouter` with a `Router` from `react-router-dom` by accident. I have mixed views on `withRouter`, sometimes it works and others not. Have you got a test repo? I'll see if I can see whats up.